# Cleaner way of logging in user once registration link in email clicked

Tags: php, html, autologin

I currently have a system where a user will register, an email is generated, they click the email, it updates the database and returns then to the site.  They then need to login.

I'm trying to remove the last step but it's getting ugly.

The only two variables I get when the link is selected is their email and the emailCode for activating.

When I'm considering doing is then writing a function that takes that email, retrieves the username and password from db and then proceed with the login function.
Although - I just realised that the password is encrypted when added to the database so not sure this would work. I'm only using SHA1 but intend on updating it at some point.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I don't know how your login works, but I'm pretty sure you don't need password in any form to sign in user programatically.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel can you elaborate please? - Think I understand what you may mean - I can get the username and just say that the login is true and voila?

Comment: What is login? Login is setting a cookie (I guess) for a user, that will identify him on subsequest requests. Login and password is not required for login to work - it's just a security feature so you are sure that you let in only real users.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, OK, I think I understand what you mean. I am using cookies.  I can only think now that I'd set the session etc when they come to the 'thansk for activating' page

Comment: Exactly. And instead of password your method to validate that this is real user will be confirmation code. For some more security you may wish to remove email from link and make confirmation codes unique.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, thanks. the confirm codes are unique. :)
I need the id to set the session so I've a small get id from db using email.  Then I can set the session.  Shame it takes so long to mess about removing email addresses from db to reset

Answer (score 0):

You should include functionality that logs the user in automatically in the function that processes the email link.  They click on the link.  It takes them back to the site and gives them the "You are registered" page.  This also sets the cookie that you use to track the user from page to page.  If you want to store information about the user in their session, then get that info when you log them in and store it in the session.